# Constructors in cases of inheritance (Squeak)

Tags: squeak

I have a class A which B inherits from. The inheritance includes a bunch of parameters, and they should all be initialized to some default values in both cases (whether we create an A object or a B object). I decided to put the initialization into the constructor of A, since the creation of B should create an A first. However, this doesn't seem to be happening automatically, and I was unable to figure out how to call the super constructor manually. Can some one help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK never mind... You use the word super. 
I guess that explains why there's no list of classes that define it in the method finder.

Answer (score 3):

You already found the solution, but here are some more notes that might help you to understand your question better:

- `super` is similar to `self`, they both represent the receiver of the message.
- `self` starts the lookup of the following message in the receiver of the message.
- `super` starts the lookup of the following message in the superclass where the implementing method is defined in.
- `self` and `super` are not messages but implicit variables, therefor you cannot find them in the message finder.